# What actually determines abilities of "shifter"?

Tags: attack-on-titan

I'm really confused by how abilities of shifters are determined in Shingeki no Kyojin. It is described really inconsistently.

For example (major spoilers):

> It is still not clear what abilities Female Titan and Attacking Titan posses. Female Titan shows ability to control other titans to some extent, also ability to crystalize host, but those abilities are shared with some other titans. Attacking Titan obtains ability to create armored plates, but it seems to be caused by serum used by Eren. Beast titan has ability to control other titans, but it was implied that that's only due to Zeke's royal blood. Also, according to arc with Eren capture, it seems properties of titan can be determined by serum used. Yet, properties of Colossus Titan and Armored Titan seem to be inherited by shifter.

So, as we can see, there are examples of abilities determined by serum, shifter power and shifter host, yet there is no real consistency. E.g. there are shifters, who have abilities only from host or serum.

Is this somehow explained anywhere?

Comment: Is this referring to the mange or the anime?  I think the latter, but I'm not sure.  Given the large discrepancy of the storyline between the two, you should indicate how much spoilage you're looking for.

Comment: I'm referencing manga, which I've read to latest available chapter, so there is no issue with possible spoilers.

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of information in the [Nine Titans article](http://attackontitan.wikia.com/wiki/Nine_Titans) and the corresponding individual articles for each of the nine titans on the Attack on Titan Wikia. From my understanding the abilities are determined by which of the nine titans is inherited by the person.